# Regexp not matching string with [] and / in Tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

I am unable to match regex with a pin name having patterns with `/` and `[]`. How to match string with this expression in tcl regexp?

## ISSUE:

```
% set inst "channel/rptrw12\[5\]"
channel/rptrw12[5]
% set pin "channel/rptrw12\[5\]/rpinv\[11\]/vcc"
channel/rptrw12[5]/rpinv[11]/vcc
% regexp -nocase "^$inst" $pin
0
```

## PASSING CASE:

```
% regexp -nocase vcc $pin
1
% set pat "ctrl/crdtfifo"
ctrl/crdtfifo
% set pin2 "ctrl/crdtfifo/iwdatabuf"
ctrl/crdtfifo/iwdatabuf
% regexp -nocase $pat $pin2
1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are fighting with RE engine metacharacters, specifically `[…]`, which defines a character set. If you want to continue using your current approach, you'll need to add more backslashes.

### But you don't have to do that!

If you are asking the question “does this string exist in that string?” you can also consider using one of these:

1. Use `string first` and check if the result (where the substring is) is not negative:

   ```
   if {[string first $inst $pin] >= 0} {
       puts "Found it"
   }
   ```
2. Use `regexp ***=`, which means “interpret the rest of this as a literal string, no metacharacters”:

   ```
   if {[regexp ***=$inst $pin]} {
       puts "Found it"
   }
   ```

If you only want to match for equality at the start of the string (you're asking “does this string *start* with that string?”) you probably should instead do one of these:

3. Use `string first` and check if the resulting index is zero:

   ```
   if {[string first $inst $pin] == 0} {
       puts "Found '$inst' at the start of '$pin'"
   }
   ```
4. Use `string equal` with the right option (very much like `strncmp()` in C, if you know that):

   ```
   if {[string equal -length [string length $inst] $inst $pin]} {
       puts "'$pin' starts with '$inst'"
   }
   ```

Comment: I tested this approach is better suited than the first one.

Answer (score 1):

If you remember your regular expressions, the `[]` syntax has special meaning in regexp. It defines a character group. For example:

```
[abc]
```

means match `a` or `b` or `c`.

Therefore the pattern:

```
channel/rptrw12[5]
```

means match the string:

```
channel/rptrw125
```

If you want to match the literal character `[` in regexp you need to escape it (same with all other characters that have meaning in regexp like `.` or `?` or `(` etc.). So your pattern should be:

```
channel/rptrw12\[5\]
```

But remember, the characters `\` and `[` has special meaning in tcl strings. So your code must do:

```
set inst "channel/rptrw12\\\[5\\\]"
```

The first `\` escapes the `\` character so that tcl will insert a single `\` into the string. The third `\` escapes the `[` character so that tcl will not try to execute a command or function named `5`.

Alternatively you can use `{}` instead of `""`:

```
set inst {channel/rptrw12\[5\]}
```

Comment: I escaped the [] in the variables using string map, and now the regexp is matching as expected.